# SVG inside input overlaps pasted long text

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

We have a custom text input component with a limit of 400 characters. When user pastes more than 400 characters we show an svg icon indicating the error inside the input. And we have a problem here in Chrome. It shows the svg icon above the text cursor and overlaps the last three characters of text (so if we had "abcde" at the end then we can see only "ab" on the screenshot below). The issue happens only on Google Chrome. It's fine on Firefox. I've fixed this behavior for the "Ctrl+v" hotkey (by calling onChange twice on input) but I cannot find now what can I do with pasting using context menu.
I need to make the cursor at the end of string to appear before the icon.

[image]

Comment: Could you provide some code?

Comment: Yes but later. I think the issue may be familiar to someone even without any example code.